# Angular "Cannot Get /" when I build - have to save .ts file every time as workaround

Tags: angular, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a .Net Core 3/Angular 7 Visual Studio 2019 project and it's started playing up but I feel like it's probably something simple.

This has just started happening it's been fine for days.

When I build and run the site I get the message:

**Cannot Get /**

But if I save a .ts file and refresh the browser it's fine.

Can anyone give me an insight into what's happening when I save the .ts file? Is there something I can trigger to run in the background permanently to avoid this somewhat tedious workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered by accident that this was occurring because of an ng build error that was not being picked up in Visual Studio. For whatever reason saving a .ts file is enough for it to be circumvented but the best solution is:

Open up a command line tool and run "ng build" and see if there's any build errors, if there are fix them and then (in my case) Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices will compile and run straight away when you run in Visual Studio